# Hibernate 6: JSON type with Instant cannot be serialized

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson

I try to switch from Spring Boot 2.7/Hibernate 5.6 to Spring Boot 3/Hibernate 6.1.
Hibernate 6 supports JSON definition type by default:

```
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private MyEntity myEntity;
```

```
    public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
        private String myString;
        private Instant myInstant;
    }
```

When I try to save this entity I've got:

```
Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling
```

but I've already `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency in POM, there was also no problem before upgrade. `ObjectMapper` is configured properly.

I've found tip that I have to configure also `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer`:

```
    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer jsonFormatMapperCustomizer(ObjectMapper objectMapper){
        return properties -> properties.put(
                AvailableSettings.JSON_FORMAT_MAPPER,
                new JacksonJsonFormatMapper(objectMapper)
        );
    }
```

but in my case it doesn't work. `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` is registered properly, but problem still exists.

Workaround that I found is to create a new mapper implements `FormatMapper` with constructor:

```
    public MyMapper() {
        this(new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules());
    }
```

and register it by `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type.json_format_mapper` property, but it's not a solution. I don't want to duplicate my ObjectMapper configuration.

I'm wondering why `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` doesn't work in this case - any idea?

Comment: For spring boot there is a specific [spring-boot-starter-json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json) json starter that includes the jackson-datatype-jsr310.

Comment: I've checked it, but it didn't change anything - moreover, I already have 4 of 6 dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-json` in my POM

Answer (score 1):

After few days I realized that problem was caused by my implementation (custom entityManagerFactory).

I had to manually add JacksonJsonFormatMapper with custom ObjectMapper to JpaPropertyMap and now it works

```
    @Bean
    public CommonHibernateProperties commonHibernateProperties(JpaProperties jpaProperties, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.JSON_FORMAT_MAPPER, new JacksonJsonFormatMapper(objectMapper));
        return new CommonHibernateProperties(properties);
    }
```

Comment: I created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17098 for this inconvenience. Would that help you or do you need other custom configurations on the `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: I've checked your PR (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/7194/commits/ddd1a3d59e7d770539034061b4255bdf42f10c76) - it's much better. However, for my needs, I have some customizations on objectMapper bean - so I have to keep this manually added part. The only way I don't need a manual override is `JacksonJsonFormatMapper` takes already configured `objectMapper` bean :) Anyway, thanks for this change